# jQuery - Remove Link when clicked

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, closest

I have 2 to 4 `links` with same `ID`s.

*Here is my code:*

```
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next Article</a>
```

What I want to achieve is to `remove` the `link` when its `clicked`. For instance: *when `link` with text **Next 2** is clicked I want to remove that `link`*.

*I have tried with this:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link').click(function () {
        $('#link').closest('a.hallo').remove();
    });
});
```

But It only removes the first link *(Next 1)* and not other ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#link').click(function () {
    $('#link').closest('a.hallo').remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next Article</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the id must be unique of the elements in html, secondly, you are targeting the element with id so every time the first element it finds with id link will be picked up, you need to use class attribute and selector.

### HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="hallo">Next 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" class="hallo">Next 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" class="hallo">Next 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" class="hallo">Next 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link5" class="hallo">Next Article</a>
```

### Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hallo').click(function () {
        $(this).remove(); // remove element which is being clicked
    });
});
```

what we have written is that whenever an element with class *hallo* is clicked remove that element `$(this)` selector will pick the element that currently generated the event which is in our case click event.

### Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hallo').click(function () {
        $(this).remove(); // remove element which is being clicked
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1" class="hallo">Next 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" class="hallo">Next 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" class="hallo">Next 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" class="hallo">Next 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link5" class="hallo">Next Article</a>
```

Comment: typo in `$('this)`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy it happens when typing fastly :D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad lol ya.. I just replaced what ever was there with `this`. Thanks for your edit though..

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 to 4 links with same IDs.

This is a big NO.. you should not have duplicate `id's` that is the issue in your code.

**Problem:** your current script `$('#link').click(function () {` it doesn't select all the elements with the same `id`. **It selects only the first element** with that id parsing from top of the HTML. So technically the event is bound only to the first element.

**Solution:** Remove the duplicate id's and write the script to work on class `hallo`. use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hallo').click(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

use class selector for click not id.

and `$(this)` - points to clicked link.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.hallo').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link" class="hallo">Next Article</a>
```